# How to Filter ListAdapter using getFilter() within a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I want to filter a ListAdapter with a search action bar, that's a SimpleAdapter. I'm struggling to understand how I can use getFilter within my onQueryTextSubmit & onQueryTextChange methods. I'm using fragments.

My onQueryTextSubmit & onQueryTextChange methods are working fine.

**Here is my onCreateOptionsMenu:**

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)   this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)   menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

      searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
     searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);   

     SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new  SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) 
        {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered
         //   adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            //  adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            System.out.println("on text chnge text: "+newText);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) 
        {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered
         //  adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
        //  adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            System.out.println("on query submit: "+query);
            return true;
        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);

  //   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

**Here is my ListAdapter:**

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), inboxList, R.layout.p_list_item,
                        new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_FROM, TAG_COUNTRY, TAG_DATE, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_SUBJECT },
                        new int[] { R.id.from, R.id.subject, R.id.country, R.id.date, R.id.mail, R.id.roundscore }) {
```

Comment: `adapter.getFilter().filter(newText)` is ok

Comment: I can't use it like that

Comment: this is how `android.widget.Filter` works, what can't you use?

Comment: it's saying I need to add cast to adapter, so i do and it becomes ((SimpleAdapter) adapter).getFilter().filter(query);. 
I get an error then: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getFilter()' on a null object reference

Comment: so your `adapter` variable is simply `null`, make sure it is initialized correctly

Comment: Thanks pskink, I'm not 100% sure where to stick the onCreateOptionsMenu section, my adapter is in my doInBackground code, so i'll need to configure out where i put it

Comment: Hi Pskink, Thanks for the help, im still struggling with my code, i'm not sure where to place my  onCreateOptionsMenu(). I have created a new question if you'd like to reply on there, it would be amazing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816425/how-to-reference-adapter-within-oncreateoptionsmenu

Answer (score 0):

Make the adapter as a global variable defined as

```
ListAdapter listAdapter;
```

Before implementing the searchView in your application make sure that the adapter is showing the appropriate results, if so then implement the search

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu,menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search_menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            listAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```