# How to reference adapter within onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

How can I reference an adapter within onCreateOptionsMenu, when the adapter is created inside OnPostExecute?

Within onCreateOptionsMenu I have two methods:

**onQueryTextChange 

onQueryTextSubmit**

In each I use **adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);.**

**What's the issue:**
My adapter can not be assigned and used with getFilter() due to the structure of my code.

Because my my adapter is created within:

**Class LoadInbox extends AsyncTask** 
**Protected String doInBackground** 
**OnPostExecute** -> Created here

How can I reference my adapter within onPostExecute to work within onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: check if adapter != null, if so call adapter.getFilter().filter(newText)

Comment: Thanks but my issue is that I can't even reference my adapter in my code, because the adapter is within OnPostExecute inside Class LoadInbox. And my onCreateOptionsMenu method is at the top of my fragment class

Comment: what do you mean: you can't even reference your adapter?

Comment: I mean when I try to use adapter.getFilter().filter(newText) , my adapter can not be associated with adapter.getFilter().filter(newText). Because of the structure of my code. I'm not sure where to put onCreateOptionsMenu so I can access my adapter to use adapter.getFilter().filter(newText).

Comment: sorry, i dont understand

Comment: Sorry it's ok, its difficult to explain, I can't access my adapter within onCreateOptionsMenu, because of the structure of my code.

Comment: so you have to change the code structure